# System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.core, Version=2.6.4.14350, Culture=neutral,

Tags: c#, visual-studio, shell, tfs, teamcity

System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.core, Version=2.6.4.14350, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or one of its dependencies. The
 system cannot find the file specified.

I am running the Test cases from teamcity using shell script and i am getting this above error, when i run the same from test explorer and it is executing fine.

Comment: Most probably yo need to add  "using  System.I.O to the list of your usings

Comment: Since he error occurs with teamcity using shell script, why you add a TFS tag in this case? Please double check  the assembly binding in your configuration file.

Comment: i am creating the defects automatically in tfs when test case got failed. so thats the reason i tag tfs.

Comment: String RepoSteps = TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentResult.StackTrace;
                        string Description = TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentResult.Message;
                        string RepoStep = RepoSteps + NewLineHandling.Entitize + Description; ---- This is my actual code where the error is encountered, i found the cause from where this error is occuring. TestExecutionContext is a class of nunit.Core namespace.

Comment: No Sir, The issue still there.